# Using AWS Glue to create table of parquet data stored in S3 in Athena

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I want to preview in Athena data that resides in an S3 bucket. The data is in parquet. This doc [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/data-sources-glue.html) describes the process of how to use AWS Glue to create a preview. One mandatory step here is to input the Column Details. This include entering the column name and its data type. I have two problems with this step:

1 - What if I have no ideas of what columns exist in the parquet file before hand (i.e. I have not seen the content of the parquet before)?

2 - What if there are hundreds if not thousands of columns in there.

Is there a way to make the this work without entering this Column Details ?

Comment: You don't need to know the column details when using a crawler. I think you misunderstood something

Comment: OK, I think you are right. I think what I was trying is to create a table from S3 using Glue (not crawler). This process asks me to enter the column detail one by one. I have edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link you provided answers your first question, I think:

> What if I have no ideas of what columns exist in the parquet file before hand

Then you should use a Glue crawler to explore the files and have it create a Glue table for you. That table will show up in the AwsDataCatalog catalog as a queryable relation.

> What if there are hundreds if not thousands of columns in there.

If you're worried about some column quota limitation, I spent some time looking around documentation to see if there is any mention of a service quota for max columns per table. I could not find any. That doesn't mean that there isn't one, but I would be surprised to see that someone generated a parquet file with more columns than Glue supports.